# show list of options in elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

HI,

I have the following problem:

*Provided a list of values, and using a formatting function passed as argument, display all its elements in a helper buffer. The user would then select one of them using the arrow keys. The returned value must be the chosen entry.*

If you have ever used reftex to insert citations, or browse-kill-ring, you know what I'm talking about. Those two examples use custom code to achieve the desired results, but perhaps there is a library that could do that.

Answer (score 11):

```
(with-output-to-temp-buffer "*Name of buffer*"
  (display-completion-list '("foo" "bar" "baz" "qux")))
```